# Why was my edit rejected? I thought it was helpful

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, suggested-edits, specific-edit

I added an important comment made by the OP to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1240064

Should I not make edits like this in the future? I thought it would be helpful to include the error message in the question. I'm just curious if I should not do this in the future.

Comment: Well, it's a *comment,* isn't it?

Comment: "This edit is incorrect **or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.**"  You did not make it clear that the *OP* was the one that made the comment.  It's important, but the way you ended up editing it in lead people to think that it was *you* making the comment.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Very True, but I believe it *should* have been included in the question. So if fellow commenters incite important information it should be left in the comments for people to dig through? (in this case not so much, but for future reference?)

Comment: @Charles, gotcha! thanks!

Comment: I have sufficient rep to bypass review but even then, for cases like you describe I add edit comments like **["clarification copied into question from comments"](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14024691/revisions "see example in rev 3 here")**

Comment: I agree with Charles.  If you'd made it clear in your edit reason that you were folding a comment the OP made into the main post, I think you would have been all right.

Comment: I understand. I guess i didn't realize that the reviewers don't see (or seek out) the context, which is why I should put more effort into the comment. Kinda makes me wonder why when I do the `review first posts` why is the question greyed out on the bottom and not more prominent?

Comment: Because you're reviewing the answer, not the question.  It gets confusing if you put two posts in there without highlighting what's actually being reviewed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Keep in mind that reviewers only see your edit and the edit message. In general they are unaware of comments or other parts of the history of that question.

You edited in a comment made by the OP. While potentially helpful, without a clear indication that this comment comes from the OP it looks like your comment. And that should never be a suggested edit. So next time clearly state where this content is coming from.